# How can I make my Xcode 8.0 Support iOS 10.2

Tags: xcode, ios

It is really difficult to download 5GB+ Xcode file each time iOS gets updated. Do we have any other option to make to new iOS support in our current version of Xcode without upgrading the version?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode updates through the Mac App Store are delta updates, meaning they only download the files necessary, rather than the entire bundle every time. This should reduce the download size.

Comment: I am installing again from App Store (Coz, cannot see update but only install). But still it shows 4.5 GB

Comment: @Jithin The first install from the Mac App Store will be the full size. You can't use the Mac App Store to update a non-MAS version. Once the MAS version is installed, you can then use the MAS delta updates.

Comment: Can you please explain what is this MAS version. I have got Xcode 8.0, which is already installed from App Store. And how MAS delta update can be done?

Comment: @Jithin If you see Install rather than Update, then you did not have Xcode installed from the Mac App Store, or you were not signed in with the same Apple ID in the MAS. Updates through the MAS can be found in the Updates tab of the App Store app — such updates are delta by default.

Comment: Yeah! Apple ID is different.